# Cant Catch WebView LoginRequest Awesomium

Tags: .net, awesomium

I am unable to catch the event of the WebView LoginRequest. Does anyone have some sample code for this? I have also tried Appending the extra header as I am trying to authenticate a proxy, but this doesn't work with Connect Requests.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.kobashicomputing.com/proxy-authentication-with-the-awesomium-browser

Comment: http://docs.awesomium.net/html/E_Awesomium_Core_WebView_LoginRequest.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer on a Popup-Infested website:

```
 AddHandler view.LoginRequest, Sub(sender As Object, e As LoginRequestEventArgs)
                                      MsgBox("asked")
                                  End Sub
```